# XPath Axes child

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, axes

I have a problem with XPath Axes child::* .
this expression `$x[1]/child::*` correctly selects all child nodes
buy this `$x[1]/child::y` it doesn't select anything, but it should select nodes with that name

this is how the variable x is valued

```
<xsl:param name="x" select="/a/b" />
```

this is the xml:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
    </c>
    <d>
    </d>
    <e>
    </e>
    <f>
    </f>
    <g>
    </g>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <y>
    </y>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c>
    </c>
    <d>
    </d>
    <e>
    </e>
    <f>
    </f>
    <g>
    </g>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    <y>
    </y>
  </b>
</a>
```

please help me.

**EDIT**

this is the really xml (with test value):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Sample XML file generated by XMLSpy v2020 rel. 2 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com)-->
<CRR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:n1="urn:crif-cribiscom-Report-Company:2012-04-01" xmlns:n2="http://www.altova.com/samplexml/other-namespace" ASYNCID="String" LUD="1957-08-13" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crif-cribiscom-Report-Company:2012-04-01 Crif.CribisCom.Report.Company.xsd">
    <BSs>
        <BS4D N="2">
            <C>
                <BSD>
                    <IBS>
                        <BH CD="1957-08-13" SC="String" SCD="String" CCD="String" CC="String" ACD="String" AC="String" SCC="String" SCCD="String" FBR="String" VN="String" BS="String" FRF="text"/>
                            <BI>
                                <IC>
                                    <SA>
                                        <A CI="St   ring" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Abis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <Ater CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <B CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <C CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <D CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Dbis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <E CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                    </SA>
                                    <SP>
                                        <A CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <B CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <C CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <D CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Dbis CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Dter CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <E CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Ebis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <F CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <G CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Gbis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                    </SP>
                                </IC>
                            </BI>
                    </IBS>
                </BSD>
                <BSD>
                    <IBS>
                        <BH CD="1957-08-13" SC="String" SCD="String" CCD="String" CC="String" ACD="String" AC="String" SCC="String" SCCD="String" FBR="String" VN="String" BS="String" FRF="text"/>
                            <BI>
                                <IC>
                                    <SA>
                                        <A CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Abis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <Ater CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <B CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <C CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <D CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Dbis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <E CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                    </SA>
                                    <SP>
                                        <A CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <B CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <C CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <D CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Dbis CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Dter CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <E CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Ebis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                        <F CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <G CI="String" V="0" D="String" SD="0" SCI="String" CCI="String"/>
                                        <Gbis CI="String" V="0" D="String"/>
                                    </SP>
                                </IC>
                            </BI>
                    </IBS>
                </BSD>
            </C>
        </BS4D>
    </BSs>
</CRR>
```

I want to select the node `../BI/IC/SA/A` or `../BI/IC/SA/Abis` or `../BI/IC/SA/Ater` ecc... in parallel with ancestor node `C/BSD`.
I hope it's more understandable.

Comment: The problem you report cannot be reproduced using your code: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBG4

Comment: Perhaps the `y` elements are in a namespace.

Comment: I have update the answer with new xml.

Comment: Now add also your XSLT and the expected result.